# SQL Server : retrieve composite primary key after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to retrieve a composite primary key from my table after inserting new rows.

This is the table design:

[image]

This is my query

```
Set Nocount on

insert into AE_Movimenta (NumContrato, ANoMov, NumMov, CodTpDoc, CodNatOper, CodCondPag, TipoMov, CodTab, CodTpEntrega, Tipo, DtMov, CodUsu, CodSetor, DtDoc, NumDoc, Serie, IdNfe, NumIP, DtSistema, CodSistema) 
values (22, YEAR(GETDATE()), 15, 1,1,0,'S',0,1,'E',GETDATE(), 4, 1, GETDATE(), '', '','', '', GETDATE(), 1)

select NumMov = @@identity

set nocount off
```

And I get a `NULL`.

[image]

In this example, the `NumMov` primary key column is set manually, but I need to get this value dynamically after insert.

Comment: @@identity only applies to `identity`-type fields. you can't expect this SINGLE value in @@identity to somehow return the *THREE* values that server as your PK

Comment: Yipes Never ever use @@Identity to retrieve a key you just put in. You can often get teh wrong value.

Comment: Ok, but how to retrieve the three values after insert?

Comment: How to get the inserted column values after insert in SQL Server is 1000x documented on the web already.

Comment: @usr it's a composite primary key, all that i find return the same "NULL". Did you read my entire question? I don't think so.

Comment: you've already GOT the three values. other than the year value, which you could generate separately so you don't run into an end-of-year condition, you already had and used the three values of the PK

Comment: I did read it and you are not the first one in the world to have this problem. https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql+server+retrieve+inserted+values first hit on my first search.

Comment: In this Example, the "NumMov" primary Key is set mannually, but i need to get this value dynamically after insert. Just ins THIS example i have the "NumMov" value on Insert, but i will not have.

Comment: I notice this question is getting downvotes.  I don't actually think this is a bad question.  Clearly Marcelo needs to learn more about SQL Server, but I don't think that makes a question like this "bad".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I downvoted because he did not do research and I do not wish to have more questions like this in SO. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@@IDENTITY` retrieves the last inserted *identity* value (subject to certain conditions about scoping).  This is quite clearly documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx).  So, if you have no column defined as an `identity` then nothing will be returned.  This really has nothing to do with primary keys, except for the fact that it is good practice to use identity columns as primary keys.

If you want information about the last records inserted (or updated or deleted), then learn to use the `output` clause.  This is the best way to get the data that was actually inserted (or updated or deleted) in the given statement.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is the documentation on the `output` clause.

Comment: Gordon, it's wrong I have a composite primary key like this table, and only set the "NumMov" as a indentity? One Collum identify the Software, another the Year and the third (NumMov) is the "unique number" of this record.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa . . . Stick with having a unique identifier for each record (in my opinion an identity column).  The `year` and `software` are attributes of the record.  For instance, you wouldn't want to have to use them for foreign key references.

Comment: BUt @@identity is the wrong thing to use even if you have an identity as your PK. If you ever add a trigger to anopther table with an identity, it will return that one. YOu want scope_identity() or OUTPUT

Answer (score 3):

You havea compostie key and so likely do not have an identiy value to retrieve..

What you need to use is the OUTPUT clause.  Look up the syntax in Books online.